# How to allow so many CIDR IP addresses easily in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have developed a web application only for users within USA. https://www.countryipblocks.net/acl.php
However, I used above websites to find out there are about more than 76,000 IP addresses or CIDR blocks within USA. It would be so much works if I must enter and allow 76,000 IP addresses one by one in AWS.

Is there a easier way of doing this? or is there a tool for only allowing so many IP addresses in AWS security group or ACL?

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 3):

Usually you would use CloudFronts [geographic restrictions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/georestrictions.html) or AWS WAF [Geographic match rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/waf-rule-statement-type-geo-match.html). This is far better then using individual IP addresses or CIDR ranges.